# How to add layers and update layer control dynamically : leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I am working with the lealflet api, where user can draw shapes to
map(image)...

Initially the layer control(handling 1 layer) is added for base map
using imageoverlay......

I have added a button of id 'newLyer' to page where click event
handles the creation of new layer.....i.e user can create new layer
and update layer control(which is now handling 2 layers)....

I have used several methods to create the layers and adding to control
but failed....

**Adding new layer to layerGroup**

```
var layerGroup = new L.LayerGroup(),
                    imageOverlayUrl = 'aa.jpg',
                    // New imageoverlay added to the layergroup
                    imageOverlay = new L.ImageOverlay(imageOverlayUrl, bounds).addTo(layerGroup),
                    // New featuregroup added to the layergroup
                    featureGroup = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(layerGroup);
```

**LayerControl where i needed to add the control(if i am correct)**

```
        var layerControl = new L.control.layers({
            'Main': layerGroup,
            //here i need to add new layer control
            }, null, { collapsed: false }).addTo(map);
```

**OnClick function with so far static code, this will be executed on click**

```
        $('#newLayer').click(function addNewLayer() {
            // Second layergroup not added to the map yet
            var layerGroupNew = new L.LayerGroup(),
                imageOverlayUrlNew = 'bb.png',
                // New imageoverlay added to the second layergroup
                imageOverlayNew = new L.imageOverlay(imageOverlayUrlNew, bounds).addTo(layerGroup2),
                // New featuregroup added to the second layergroup
                featureGroupNew = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(layerGroupNew);
        });
```

**In Short**

Initially, i have one layer with its control, now onclick function
creates the new layer which will be added to the map but how i can add
this layer into layerControl....

If someone has idea about how to do this sort of thing, please do help,,,, any kind of help or reference will be appreciated....
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for `L.Control.Layers`:

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers

You'll see that `L.Control.Layers` has a `addBaseLayer` method:

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-addbaselayer

> Adds a base layer (radio button entry) with the given name to the control.

Thus you can do:

```
layerControl.addBaseLayer(newBaseLayer, 'My New BaseLayer');
```

And you're good to go. As you see, you could have spared yourself the trouble of posting this question if you would have taken a look at the [reference](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html). Leaflet is very well documented. I've personally learned most that i know about Leaflet by reading the docs completely once of twice. Good luck with your project, cheers!

Comment: you are superhero thanks for answer, i read some and missed some and understood few as i am new to js,,, my mistake......